# Mysql get data from between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried googling and looking at other answers to my problem however I have tried them all but it still returns no results. however if I take out the deskfrom and deskto bit it returns all the results.

I have a date and I'm using it to fetch data from a table

```
 deskfrom-------deskto------ etc
2013-11-25    2013-12-25    xxxxx
2013-10-25    2013-12-13    xxxxx

$bookdate = preg_replace("[^A-Z/ a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['bdate']);
    $bookdate = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $bookdate));
    $bookdate = date("Y-m-d", $bookdate);
    $bookcompany = preg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['comp']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE company='$bookcompany' AND deskfrom<='$bookdate' AND deskto>='$bookdate' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_x,$sql);
```

this will return nothing  and im not sure why is any one able to help ... if I remove the bit after company='$bookcompany'  it works fine

Comment: done any basic debugging? a) check that $bookdate is what you think it should be? dumped out `$sql` to see if it's built correctly?

Comment: I have tried a few thing now $sql but checked $bookdate and that is the correct result  will try $sql now

Comment: Confirm that `deskfrom` and `deskto` are temporal data types and that `$bookdate` is a valid temporal literal.

Comment: SELECT * FROM company WHERE company='true story' AND deskfrom<='2013-12-11' AND deskto>='2013-12-11' sql returned result

Comment: Are you sure you've got the `<=` and `>=` right?  It might help for legibility if you go with `WHERE ... AND '2013-12-11' BETWEEN deskfrom AND deskto`.

Comment: I'll try that now. however I did change <= and >= around just to be sure be for posting I'm not that good yet but did not want to look foolish.........again lol

Comment: @MarcB very good point. If you want between use `BETWEEN` instead of `<=` and `>=` and if you want everything but between use `NOT BETWEEN` it really does make your code so much easier to read later on as well.

Comment: Marc B can you post that as an answer as its worked thank you